# Estimating probability of observing greater than X events based on a current population and historical rates

Tags: time-series, probability, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

Let's say I have a population that varies from month to month, and per month, there are X number of failures. Based on historical rates, I am trying to find the probability of observing Y or greater failures for the population of the current month, based on historical rates.

For example, we have the following data:

```
Month   Failures    Population  
1       20          11969
2       14          15607
3       37          19900
4       17          25038
5       25          29992
6       30          35645
```

I am trying to figure out the probability of observing 30 failures out of 35,645 items, given the previous months' observations.

I have several questions about distributions:

To find the distribution of my data, do I look at the number of failures? or failures per population unit?  Plotting failures, it seems to follow a negative binomial distribution. Plotting failures per population unit, it seems to follow a lognormal/gamma/Weibull distribution. (This was found using the `fitdist` function in R.)

What I've tried already is averaging the rate (failures divided by population) over the previous months, and then using that value times the current population to get the lambda value for a Poisson probability calculation. Then I used the ppois function in R to calculate the poisson probability of observing 30 failures in month 6, based on the calculated lambda. However, the more I look at it, the more I'm starting to think I can't use poisson because of the changing population over time, and because my mean and variance are very different.

I believe my data is overdispersed, so I looked into gamma-poisson mixture, but am not sure how to algorithmically implement it, nor if it's the right approach. I read up on negative binomial distribution and how it arises from a continuous mixture of Poisson distributions, but am unsure if this is the right fit for my data as well.

What is the best course of action to find the probability of observing 30 failures in month 6, based on the observations in months 1-5? I have about 40 total months of data. How do I find the best distribution to fit my data to?